# How can I use SEDE to get the answers that earned the most reputation through bounties?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I'm trying to create a query to check for the highest awarded bounties, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT TOP 10
Posts.Id [Post Link], Score, BountyAmount
FROM
    Posts, Votes
ORDER BY BountyAmount Desc
```

But it [isn't giving me](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/980644/highest-score-awarded-bounties) the desired result. What am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[These](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/981360) are the answers that earned the most reputation with bounties:

```
SELECT TOP 100
   SUM(V.BountyAmount) as 'Bounty Amount',
   COUNT(*) as 'Amount of Bounties',
   V.PostId AS [Post Link]
FROM
   Votes V 
INNER JOIN Posts P ON P.id = V.PostId
WHERE
   P.PostTypeId = 2 AND V.VoteTypeId=9 
GROUP BY V.PostId
ORDER BY 'Bounty Amount' DESC
```

And [these](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/981362) are the questions where most reputation has been spent in bounties:

```sql
SELECT TOP 100
   SUM(V.BountyAmount) as 'Bounty Amount',
   COUNT(*) as 'Amount of Bounties',
   V.PostId AS [Post Link]
FROM
   Votes V 
INNER JOIN Posts P ON P.Id = V.PostId
WHERE
   P.PostTypeId = 1 AND V.VoteTypeId=8 
GROUP BY V.PostId
ORDER BY 'Bounty Amount' desc
```

Comment: You failed to mention what the asker was missing. Namely a join-condition, a sum, and a grouping.